# Why does the webmethods debugger skip the loop step?

Tags: webmethods

I'm trying to create a flow service where one service outputs a list of files and the `loop` step is suppose to loop over that list of files. When I debug it, the debugger for some reason skips the loop step and goes to the next step below `LOOP`. Any suggestions/advice will be appreciated. Thank you

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx5Mu.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gDJx.png)

Comment: This is likely caused by readConfigOutput/file_group either not existing in the pipeline, or not being a list. Can you please provide a screenshot of the contents of the pipeline prior to the first loop step?

Comment: I'd bet the list is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are trying to loop over document or documentList? And also check what is coming in pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, they also are some Designer fixes that resolve this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

start the input array with a slash: /readConfigOuput/file_group